# Converting List<List<Integer>> to ArrayList<int[]>

Tags: java, list, arraylist

So i'm creating a method that looks like this:

```
public static ArrayList<int[]> permuteArray(int[] array)
```

I have a helper method that looks like this:

```
  public static List<List<Integer>> permuteArray(List<List<Integer>> list, List<Integer> result, int [] arr) {
    if(result.size() == arr.length){
        list.add(new ArrayList<>(result));
    }
    else{
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            if(result.contains(arr[i]))
            {
                continue;
            }
            result.add(arr[i]);
            permuteArray(list, result, arr);
            result.remove(result.size() - 1);
        }

    }
    return list;
}
```

I have this line : `List<List<Integer>> permute = permuteArray(list, new ArrayList<>(), array);`
But i want to convert the `List<List<Integer>>` to `ArrayList<int[]>`. Is this possible for the helper method to return ArrayList<int[]> or if the original method can?

Comment: Are you asking if the helper method can directly return an `ArrayList<int[]>` instead of `List<List<Integer>>`? It probably can. It would be easier to answer if you included the code of that method.

Comment: I'll add it right now

Comment: @Eran i just added the method

Comment: Why do you want to return an `ArrayList` specifically?

Comment: practicing with array-list and the prompt wants me to return an ` ArrayList<int[]>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While modifying the original method might be the better way to go, this is the answer to the title, which is 'Converting `List<List<Integer>>` to `ArrayList<int[]>`'

```
List<List<Integer>> original = ...;
ArrayList<int[]> arraylist = original.stream()
    .map(sub -> sub.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray())
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
List<List<Integer>> lst = new ArrayList<>();
lst.add(List.of(1, 2, 3));
lst.add(List.of(4, 5, 6));
lst.add(List.of(7,8,9));

ArrayList<int[]> newList = lst.stream()
        .map(x -> x.stream().mapToInt(k -> k).toArray())
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using the below to convert List<List> to ArrayList<int[]>,

```
list.stream().map(x -> x.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray())
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```